# Find prime pairs satisfying the equation

Tags: prime-numbers

Find all ordered pairs $(p_{k},p_{k+1})$, where $p_k$ denotes the $k$-th prime, such that for every $m\ \in  \mathbb{N}$ there exists $\alpha \in  \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $\Omega(\alpha) = m$ so that $p_{k+1} + 1 = \alpha p_{k}$, where $\Omega(x)$ denotes total number of prime numbers in prime factorization of $x$.

Source: http://mishabucko.wordpress.com

Comment: Typically $\Omega$ notation means that there is some constant multiplier that provides a lower bound. Do you have such a constant in mind? Otherwise it seems like the problem is ill-posed and dependent on the unknown constant multiplier.

Comment: Omega means: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_prime

Comment: you should clarify this in your posting, because $\Omega$ has a well-documented different usage in the computer science literature. All you have to do is specify that $\Omega$ counts the number of prime divisors.

Comment: Added this information to the problem description. Thank you for your insight.

Comment: What have you tried so far?